# fill empty array using loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

i'm new to python and i'm asked to make a basic calculator using 3 input int, int, str. the input and output should be like this:
INPUT
1 2 ADD
4 100 MUL
5 2 DIV
100 10 SUB

OUTPUT
3
400
2
90

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
angk1, angk2, ope = input().split(" ")
angk1, angk2, ope = [int(angk1),int(angk2),str(ope)]
hasil = []
i = hasil
L = 0
while True:
    for L in range(1, 500):
        if ope=='ADD':
            hasil[L] = (angk1+angk2)
        elif ope=='MUL':
            hasil[L] = (angk1*angk2)
        elif ope=='DIV':
            hasil[L] = (angk1/angk2)
        elif ope=='SUB':
            hasil[L] = (angk1-angk2)
    L += 1
    i.extend(hasil)
    if input()=='STOP':
        break
print i
print 'Done'
```

and the result is:

```
'123 123 ADD'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    hasil[L] = (angk1+angk2)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

can anyone point my mistakes? any help appreciated.

Comment: In Python, you *cannot* enlarge a list by assigning to nonexistent indexes - you have to use the `.append()` or `.extend()` methods.

Comment: I notice that you have `5 2 DIV` as `2`. Do you want it to be `2` or `2.5`?

Comment: @JoePatten i forgot about that, i think both are okay because i wasn't asked to make the answer float or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned your program up a little. I added a message `print('Type number number OPERATOR to perform operation. Type STOP to end program.')` at the beginning to guide the reader. Also, I took out the for loop (you had a for loop and a while loop, which were redundant. Also, you need to use append when adding to your list as you are starting with an empty list, so passing in an index will throw an error.

```
hasil = []
print('Type number number OPERATOR to perform operation. Type STOP to end program.')
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'STOP':
        break
    angk1, angk2, ope = inp.split(" ")
    angk1, angk2, ope = [int(angk1),int(angk2),str(ope)]
    if ope=='ADD':
        hasil.append(angk1+angk2)
    elif ope=='MUL':
        hasil.append(angk1*angk2)
    elif ope=='DIV':
        hasil.append(angk1/angk2)
    elif ope=='SUB':
        hasil.append(angk1-angk2)
for i in hasil:
    print(i)
print('Done')
```

Input:

```
1 2 ADD    
4 100 MUL    
5 2 DIV
100 10 SUB
```

Output:

```
3
400
2.5
90
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

try building the list like:

```
 if ope=='ADD':
        x = (angk1+angk2)
        hasil.append(x)
```

and you might want to print the value of L, it looks like it might not be what you're intending it to be based on the loop structure.